# Unit Test cases for iMessage extension iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, imessage-extension, xctestcase

I have added an iMessage extension as a target in my current app & I am trying to add unit tests for iMessage extension I tried adding the test cases for the iMessage extension but getting an error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "type metadata accessor for Target.ViewController", referenced from:
>         TargetTest.ViewControllerTests.setUp () -> () in ViewControllerTests.o
>         type metadata accessor for Target.ViewController? in ViewControllerTests.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**My Observation: On adding iMessage Extension target, Apple does not give option to add unit test cases for that extension, neither I can select the iMessage target while adding unit test target manually.**

Has anyone added unit test cases in iMessage extension or know how to resolve this error in this situation.

Comment: provide your code..

Comment: @SagarBhut What code do you want?

Comment: I've not tried to do this personally so I'm not sure that it's possible. But maybe look to extract your code into a framework and test the code in the framework, then the code in the message extension can be minimal and you can reuse the code elsewhere at a later date. Please bare in mind that I'm only suggesting this as I've not got any experience with creating a message app extension so don't know the true solution to this.